# Highlight selected cell of a flex data grid

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid

I have a flex data grid.I need to highlight the selected cell of the data grid.can u please help me?

Answer (score 1):

AdvancedDataGrid does have a property selectionMode. Change property value single cell or multiple cells, you can select and highlight cells.

Comment: You are right, but the normal Spark DataGrid has ths property a well.

Answer (score 0):

DataGrid automatically highlights the selected row ([see the examples](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/DataGrid.html#includeExamplesSummary))

If you're looking for a table-like component, check out Grid or Tile.

It would also help if you would post your source code so that we would know what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I want that particular row remain highlighted in datagrid.. with same or different color..

Answer (score 0):

I know data grid automatically highlights the selected row.But I'm not searching for row highlight. I'm searching for cell highlight.For example say if I will click on 1st cell of data grid, instead of highlighting the first row it will only highlight the first cell(row-0,col-0)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

by setting datagrid property -> selectionMode="singleCell"